# Android Adview not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to slice 3 views inside a LinearLayout. But Adview is not showing up. Here is my layout file. I have given weightSum to 10 and divided that among 3 views.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context="in.example.LandingActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/landing_header_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1390609726414683/1349170451"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have 3 views and you want to devide it in top, center and bottom .. its better to use relative layout so that you can create it easily using following.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_spinner"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1390609726414683/1349170451"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this initialize

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
```

then load your ad

```
 mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and check if its loaded or failed by adding AdListener on your adView

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        Log.i("Ads", "onAdFailedToLoad");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
        // covers the screen.
        Log.i("Ads", "onAdOpened");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        Log.i("Ads", "onAdLeftApplication");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
        // to the app after tapping on an ad.
        Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `android:layout_weight="3"` attribute for child views inside of `LinearLayout`, you should specify layout height as `0dp`:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Also this attributes:

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

are used only in `RelativeLayout`, not `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

set the height 0dp instead of wrap_content. If you set it wrap_content it will take size of screen as its requirement so change it to 0dp and check.